# over with points and polygons in R: get the name of the polygons

Tags: r, polygon

In my `data` I have a list of signals with lat / long.

I have a shape file that I imported with `readOGR()` and I called it `polygons`.

With the code

```
data$inside.polygons <- !is.na(over(data, as(polygons, "SpatialPolygons")))
```

I have a new variable in my `data` called `inside.polygons` . It is a logical variable describing if the signal is inside the polygon (TRUE) or not (FALSE).

Is it possible to add a new column with the name of the name of the polygon?

I create a new table with

```
polygons.table <- data.frame(polygons)
```

and I got in $Polygon.name the name of each polygons

```
> str(polygons.table)
'data.frame':   233 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Country   : Factor w/ 9 levels "Denmark","Estonia",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 4 9 9 ...
 $ Polygon.name: Factor w/ 237 levels "Aalborg","Aalborg Portland",..: 114 115 69 192 193 8 237 231 230 224 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num  0.0339 0.0209 0.0399 0.1628 0.1343 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num  5.64e-05 2.26e-05 4.22e-05 5.25e-04 5.30e-04 ...
 $ LOCodes   : Factor w/ 193 levels "DEBOF","DEFLF",..: NA NA 155 184 184 137 193 15 191 192 ...
 $ Links     : Factor w/ 26 levels "http://eng.port-bronka.ru/",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

How could I add the Polygon.name to each signals that are inside the polygon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

got it with:

```
inside.polygon2 <- over(data, polygons[,"Polygon.name"])
```

and then I add it to my data

```
data$polygon.name <- inside.polygon2$Polygon.name
```